# Change shopping-cart count in header in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm adding a shopping cart in my site header( which is a shared component). It shows the number of items in cart.
I'm initializing the cart count when user logs in and add it to localstorage as 0 count.

```
cartCount: number = 0;
localStorage.setItem("cart_count", JSON.stringify(this.cartCount));
```

When item's quantity is changed, I'm setting it into `cart_count` like this:

```
 localStorage.setItem("cart_count", JSON.stringify(item.quantity));
```

How can I let it change the count in my header as well without refreshing the page?

Should I make shopping-cart as a new component and add it to header and then refresh only that component? If yes, how can I refresh that component?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this is pretty much the purpose of a shared service and rxjs.

you'd make some cart service:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class CartService {
  private cartCount = new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
  cartCount$ = this.cartCount.asObservable();
  setCartCount(count: number) {
    // encapsulate with logic to set local storage
    localStorage.setItem("cart_count", JSON.stringify(count));
    this.cartCount.next(count);
  }

  constructor() {
    // can check local storage here to initialize?
  }
}
```

then any time you want to set a new count, you inject the service and calll the `setCartCount` method, and when you want to be notified of updates, you inject the service and subscribe to the `cartCount$` observable:

```
constructor(private cartService: CartService) {

  this.countSub = this.cartService.cartCount$.subscribe(
    count => {
      // this runs everytime the count changes
      this.cartCount = count;
    }
  )

  this.cartService.setCartCount(0); // init to 0?
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.countSub.unsubscribe(); // important to unsubscribe
}
```

you could also use the async pipe instead of subscribing directly:

```
constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
  this.cartCount$ = this.cartService.cartCount$
}
```

and in template use the async pipe:

```
{{ cartCount$ | async }}
```

Comment: I tried your code. Inititalized cartcount with 0 when user logs in. But I'm stuck at how cartcount will be displayed. It shows nothing in template. In console it returns observable but how can I show the number in template?

Comment: all of that information is in my answer already. you need to learn more about observables and rxjs to be an angular developer

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a Subject.

For a quick example, something like this:

```
export class CartService {
  ...
  private cartCount = new Subject<number>();
  ...

  getCartCount(): Observable<number> {
    return this.cartCount.asObservable();
  }

  setCardCount(item: any) {
    localStorage.setItem("cart_count", JSON.stringify(item.quantity));
    this.cartCount.next(localStorage.getItem("cart_count"));
  }
...
```

Comment: I'm calling setCardCount(0) when user logs in so that count initializes to 0 first. But when I call getCartCount(), it doesn't gives me 0

Comment: There was an error in the code. I fixed it (`getCartCount(): Observable<number>`). Instead of number, the code was boolean.

Comment: No issues. I already had it fixed. Issue is when I call getCartCount(), it returns Observable. How can I get this cartCount in template? I tried `{{cartCount|async}}`, but it doesn't works